# Insert picture into excel MAC (VBA)

Tags: image, macos, excel, insert, vba

I'm trying to insert an online image to a cell in an excel worksheet. The code I use works perfectly in Excel 2016 for Windows. But not in Excel 365 for MAC: no pictures are showing (I allready tried to set all MAC security-options to the lowest options).

Who could give me a hint?

Like in my code below, the (dynamic) url is in Sheets("grafisch").Range("B87") and the picture is placed in Sheets("Sjabloon").Range("a3").

The url is basically: "https://www.adress.com/pict" and it does not end with a filetype like .jpg or .png

```
Sub Imginsert()
Sheets("Sjabloon").Range("a3").Select
Dim cellValue As String
Dim pic As Picture
cellValue = Sheets("grafisch").Range("B87").Value
If cellValue = "" Then Exit Sub
Set pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(cellValue)
pic.Name = "Picture1"
End Sub
```

Comment: did you figure this out?